# How does the use of result as an accumulator fit into Haskell's immutability model?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and exploring its purely functional approach to programming. I've come across patterns involving accumulator variables and what appears to be shadowing in recursive functions. My understanding is that Haskell values are immutable, and I'm curious about how the use of an accumulator variable and shadowing fits into this paradigm.

I've been experimenting with Haskell and trying to understand how recursion works within its purely functional paradigm. Here's what I've attempted so far:
I've written a simple function, doubleList, that doubles each element in a list using tail recursion and an accumulator variable. The code is as follows:

```
    doubleList :: [Int] -> [Int]
    doubleList xs = go [] xs
        where go result [] = result
              go result (x:xs) = go (result++[2*x]) xs
```

I've noticed that the result variable is used as an accumulator, and it seems to be shadowed in each recursive call. I understand that Haskell values are immutable, but I'm struggling to grasp how this apparent shadowing fits into the functional paradigm.
I'm curious if there are alternative approaches or best practices for achieving a similar result in Haskell without relying on what looks like mutable behavior.
I'm reaching out for insights or explanations to deepen my understanding of Haskell's functional programming concepts. Any guidance on how to approach recursion, accumulators, and shadowing in Haskell would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The accumulator is each time a different variable. You make a call with a different parameter.

Comment: Does the garbage collector in Haskell remove different variables from memory? Can high memory consumption occur due to recursive functions pushing stack frames onto the call stack, potentially causing more than iterations?

Comment: Haskell usually does not work with a call stack, but with a thunk.

Comment: Recursive functions are actually computed at runtime and use lazy evaluation instead of immediate computation.?

Comment: the compiler will analyze whether the recursive call is required, if not, then it is indeed lazy. If it is, it will keep manipulating the thunk directly. But it thus does not work with a call stack.

Comment: The compiled code can use mutability; *Haskell's* immutability semantics simply prevent you from writing code in which the resulting mutability can bite you.

Comment: Note that this question doesn't seem specific to accumulators. Any recursive function will have this property that its variables can be different on each recursive iteration. In fact, even non-recursive functions have this property across multiple calls. Consider the mathematical function `x ^ 2`. If I then compute `0 ^ 2 = 0` and `1 ^ 2 = 1` then the variable `x` will have been "assigned" two different values.

Comment: What does "shadowing" mean to you? It is a commonly-accepted term that usually means there is some lexical scope containing two variables with the same name, for which therefore only one can be referenced. But this usage doesn't seem to match your usage, because in each code snippet you posted, each lexical scope only contains one variable of each name (with the possible exception of `xs`, but you otherwise don't appear to be talking about this variable). If you can clarify what *you* mean by "shadow", it may make your question easier to answer.